# How to convert a Headers entrySet.forEach to a String Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, httpserver

I am working on an HttpServer using the com.sun package and need to store the headers from the HttpExchange into a String array but I'm not sure how to.

I get the headers using:

```
Headers requestHeaders = exchange.getRequestHeaders();
```

And then I'm able to output them to the console using this:

```
requestHeaders.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

But instead of printing to the console, what is the best way to save them to a String array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the keys use :-

```
String[] keyArray = requestHeaders.entrySet().stream()
                                  .map(Entry::getKey)
                                  .toArray(String[]::new);
```

To get the values use :-

```
String[] valuesArray = requestHeaders.values().stream().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I needed.  Is there any way to put the keys with the values in one array in a more simple fashion or just append both arrays to a new third one?

Comment: You could do something like this : `map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() + "," + e.getValue()).toArray(String[]::new);` But it wouldn't make much sense - I prefer the other way.